# Cannot figure out constructor error

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, java.util.scanner, extends

I've been struggling with the following assignment for sometime now. The assignment is to create a program that reads lines of text from an input file and then determines the percentage of words that are 1 letter in length, 2 letters, etc. The problem is is that my class extends another class and I'm running into constructor problems, although there are none that I see.

The class that mine extends:

```
public abstract class FileAccessor{
  String fileName; 
  Scanner scan;

  public FileAccessor(String f) throws IOException{
    fileName = f;
    scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
  }

  public void processFile() { 
    while(scan.hasNext()){
      processLine(scan.nextLine());
    }
    scan.close();
  }

  protected abstract void processLine(String line);

  public void writeToFile(String data, String fileName) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileName);
      pw.print(data);
      pw.close();
   }
}
```

My class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class WordPercentages extends FileAccessor{
   public WordPercentages(String s){
     super.fileName = s;
     super.scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
      }
   public void processLine(String file){
      super.fileName=file;
      int totalWords = 0;
      int[] length = new int[15];
      scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(super.fileName));
      while(super.scan.hasNext()){
         totalWords+=1;
         String s = scan.next();
         if (s.length() < 15){
            length[s.length()]+=1;
            }
         else if(s.length() >= 15){
            length[15]+=1;
            }
      }
   }

   public double[] getWordPercentages(){
      double[] percentages = new double[15];
      for(int j = 1; j < percentages.length; j++){
         percentages[j]+=length[j];
         percentages[j]=(percentages[j]/totalWords)*100;
         }
      return percentages; 
      }
   public double getAvgWordLength(){
      double average;
      for(int j = 1; j<percentages.length; j++){
         average+=(j*percentages[j])/totalWords;
         }
      return average;
      }
}
```

And finally the error that I'm getting when running my driver class:

```
WordPercentages.java:8: error: constructor FileAccessor in class FileAccessor cannot be applied to given types;
   public WordPercentages(String s) {
                                   ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you extend another class, the first statement in the subclass constructor must be a call to the superclass constructor. If you do not do that explictly it will call `super()` implicitly. In your case, the super constructor expects a `String`, which is not provided, thus the error.

So where you do:

```
public WordPercentages(String s){
   super.fileName = s;
   super.scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
}
```

You should do:

```
public WordPercentages(String s){
   super(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not explicitly called the superclass constructor in `WordPercentages`, so Java inserts an implicit call to the default constructor in `FileAccessor`.  The superclass part of the object must be constructed too.  However, you have no such no-argument constructor in `FileAccessor`.

You are attempting to initialize the superclass part of the object in the subclass constructor.  Instead, let the superclass constructor take care of it.

```
public WordPercentages(String s){
    super(s); 
}
```

You'll still have to catch the `IOException` that the superclass constructor throws (or declare the subclass constructor that it `throws IOException`).